# PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for lastMoveDate in class com.hib.objects.GameBoard

Tags: java, hibernate, getter-setter

I've named the class variable with `camel casing`.This is the class, which seems to be the culprit.

```
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import java.sql.Date;

public class GameBoard
{
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastMoveDate;

    /**
     * @return the lastMoveDate
     */
    public Date getLastMoveDate() {
        return lastMoveDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastMoveDate the lastMoveDate to set
     */
    public void setLastMoveDate(Date lastMoveDate) {
        this.lastMoveDate = lastMoveDate;
    }

}
```

The class has several other variables such as `playerOneFk`, `playerTwoFk` and `gameLobbyFk` (hibernate is able to track each `setter-getter` on these variables, but is throwing exceptions with the `last_move_date` column).

I've also tried the method names `setlastMoveDate` and `getlastMoveDate` (with no luck..), The properties.. for `lastMoveDate`

```
<property name="lastMoveDate" type="date" column="last_move_date" />
```

And the caught exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [authapi] in context with path [/TTTserver] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for lastMoveDate in class com.hib.objects.GameBoard
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getGetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertyGetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at com.hib.objects.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    at nz.ac.massey.cs.capstone.auth.authapi.processRequest(authapi.java:42)
    at nz.ac.massey.cs.capstone.auth.authapi.doGet(authapi.java:74)
```

Comment: You need to set up correctly your hibernate context.

Comment: Please show your package imports so we can see what kind of Date you are using.

Comment: @Vash thanks! :) I've also just setup the context too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hibernate, the property type "date" maps to a java.sql.Date.

If you are using a java.util.Date, you will want your property type to be "timestamp".

Using "date" as you are now will cause it to look for a getter/setter that operates on a java.sql.Date, and it won't be able to find it.

See [Hibernate basic type reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic) (6.1.1.12 and 6.1.1.14).

*Edit: Addressing some naming convention concerns:*

Hibernate obeys standard bean naming conventions:

- Field: someField
- Property: someField (same as field name)
- Getter: getSomeField() or isSomeField() (if it is a boolean)
- Setter: setSomeField()

Comment: Thanks! +1 rep, I changed my imports from `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` :) and everything is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

`<property name="LastMoveDate" type="date" column="last_move_date" />`

should work...

Comment: Thanks, do you know why it throws exceptions while the first letter is lowercase (and the method name after `set-get` is also lowercase)?

Comment: @Killrawr The method name after set-get should start with uppercase, and the property name starts with lowercase. Hibernate is consistent with the rules for bean field/setter/getter names (`someField`, `getSomeField()` or `isSomeField()`, `setSomeField()`). I exclusively use this naming convention with Hibernate -- if you are observing something different, that is very odd.

Comment: My `get-set` are generated from the netbeans `refactor -> encapsulate fields`, that's why I'm a little confused on why this was even occuring.